# Parse unicode to python data type

Tags: python, unicode, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm working on dataflow with python.I'm facing issue while inferring data type using inbuilt type() in python.

I'm tried encode that value using utf-8 and apply type() on values but it return str types of all values where as I required actual python data type like int,float.

I'm getting dictionary as input and after that I'm parsing i'm reading it csv reader.

```
def parse_method(self, string_input):
        # Strip out return characters and quote characters.
        values = re.split(",",
                          re.sub('\r\n', '', re.sub(u'"', '', string_input)))
        reader = csv.reader(values)

         for csv_row in reader:
             decoded_values=[x.decode('utf8') for x in csv_row]
             for value in decoded_values:
                 print(value)
                 print(type(value))

        row = dict( zip(('state', 'gender', 'year', 'name', 'number',
                         'created_date'),
                values))


        return row
```

```
Sample Output-

AK
<type 'list'>
F
<type 'list'>
1910
<type 'list'>
Lucy
<type 'list'>
6
<type 'list'>
11/28/2016
<type 'list'>
```

```
Expected output-


AK
<type 'str'>
F
<type 'str'>
1910
<type 'int'>
Lucy
<type 'str'>
6
<type 'int'>
11/28/2016
<type 'date'>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].  This code, if corrected with proper imports and removing `self` from the parameter list, can execute, but it returns nothing like your output example.  Provide sample input, code that runs, and expected vs. actual output.  Also specify Python version since the `csv` module is quite different between Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Also, look into `csv.DictReader`.

Answer (score 2):

The csv reader will return all values as strings. If you need to use them as int, float, etc. You must convert them from string to the appropriate type.

For the relevant numeric csv columns you can do a simple string to int/float conversion like this

```
my_int = int("21")
my_float = float("21.1")
```

Comment: This  will work but I want to my code generic means each column infer data type automatically because I din't know which column int and float.

Comment: The technique I have seen for this is to try parsing to float, and catching the exception if it fails. Then do the same for int, etc. Then your code can just try each one and stick with the one that succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you confuse with Python 2 and 3. Str is unicode in Python 3
https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#unicode